# Paranoid about iOS Blocks and Retain Cycles

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I've become a little paranoid with blocks and the possibility of creating a retain cycle.  I'm using a block based version of the `UIAlertView` class which allows you to use blocks instead of delegate methods.  I use a lot of these Alertviews, so I'm often calling into instance methods that do a lot of heavy lifting.

Would the assignments I make in the method `someInstanceMethod` cause a retain cycle?
(I am using ARC for memory management.)

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
[doWorkAndThen:^{
   [weakSelf someInstanceMethod];
}];

-(void) someInstanceMethod{
    //will either of the assignments below cause a retain cycle?
    self.iVar = @"data";
    [self setIvar:@"data";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. `-someInstanceMethod` is not a block. The fact that you're calling it from one is irrelevant. *Only* references *inside* the block itself can cause retains, and since your only reference inside your block is a `__weak` variable you're fine.

Incidentally, if you really want to ease your mind, you should modify your block-based `UIAlertView` class to throw away all the blocks when the view is dismissed. This way even if you do create a retain cycle, it will be broken automatically as soon as the alert view goes away.

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  I'm feeling a lot better about blocks now!